# Remove multiple whitespace element in an array php

Tags: php

I have an array which contains multiple white space element. Below is an array :

```
Array ( [0] => Intermarché [1] => catalogue Intermarché [2] => promotion [3] => Intermarche [4] => produit en réduction [5] => )
```

5th indexed element in an array has double white space.

I tried `array_filter($array)` php function but it removes only one white space element. Is there any array function in php to remove elements which has n number of white spaces ?

Input :

```
$array = [
    "Intermarché",
    " ",
    "promotion",
    "  ",
    "        "
];
```

Expected Output :

```
$array = [
    "Intermarché",
    "promotion"
];
```

Comment: You could try an `array_map()`, then in the `array_map()` callback trim the string if it's empty return nothing, else return the string. `array_map()` will return to you the array, with no empty values

Comment: `array_filter($array, array_map('trim', $array));` ?

Comment: This is not working @nice_dev

Comment: What do you actually want to achieve? Remove white spaces, remove white space elements? Remove multiple whaite spaces, filter out?

Comment: My question clearly explains what i want. I want to remove an element in an array which has multiple white space

Comment: @VinoCoder Can you share a reproducible example link? with expected input and output?

Comment: I have added input and an expected output in the question @nice_dev

Comment: @VinoCoder my [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73543231/5841606) gives you the output and works with PHP >= 5.6

Comment: @VinoCoder what should be the output for `Test. `?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `array_filter()` by providing `trim()` as a callback.
Which trims the value and then checks if it would be empty. It does not change actually the values.

```php
$myArray = array( 
    0 => "Intermarché ",
    1 => "catalogue Intermarché             ",
    2 => "promotion ",
    3 => "Intermarche",
    4 => "produit en réduction" ,
    5 => "  ",
    6 => ""
);
    

$myArray = array_filter($myArray,  'trim');
var_dump($myArray);
```

which gives you

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(13) "Intermarché "
  [1]=>
  string(35) "catalogue Intermarché             "
  [2]=>
  string(10) "promotion "
  [3]=>
  string(11) "Intermarche"
  [4]=>
  string(21) "produit en réduction"
}
```

[Link to code Sandbox](https://onlinephp.io/?s=bY9NDoIwEIXXkHCHkZgACQn-bxCNCxeegjRQpYZSMmlNOBLn4GK2RYwau2in733z2tkf26r13CSBcyMpQicUQiFKChVFGgNt7qKbea4z590JkXSQATFnCFp0FpAdwL-YVk6wqIYe_NgYS2sURJJa3BSFL-RzjfjK4i0KLiQTzUtd_6TTUd5McKmY1D8EHPpSFabRB0tsLTGF7-zN12WU6u3PMPmV1fqRcNJjgEAi40GUmjEfBPNS8fbtm5wn&v=8.1.9)

Comment: I was first thinking OP wanted that, but it seems that he want to get read of `$array[4]` because it as more than one space

Answer (score -1):

You can use [array_map()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map) to clean them and [array_filter()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter) to remove empty ones afterwards.

Demo: https://3v4l.org/LenLJ

```
$myArray = [
    "Intermarché ",
    "catalogue Intermarché             ",
    "promotion ",
    "Intermarche",
    "produit en réduction" ,
    "  ",
    ""
];

$noDoubleWhitespace = array_filter(
    array_map(
        fn($string) => trim(preg_replace('/\s{2,}/u','', $string)),
        $myArray
    )
);

var_dump($noDoubleWhitespace);
```

gives

```
array(5) {
  [0] =>
  string(12) "Intermarché"
  [1] =>
  string(22) "catalogue Intermarché"
  [2] =>
  string(9) "promotion"
  [3] =>
  string(11) "Intermarche"
  [4] =>
  string(21) "produit en réduction"
}
```

Below PHP 7.4 use

```
$noDoubleWhitespace = array_filter(
    array_map(
        function ($string) {
            return trim(preg_replace('/\s{2,}/u', '', $string));
        },
        $myArray
    )
);
```

Comment: Im getting parse error `PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW), expecting ',' or ')'`

Comment: @VinoCoder You have a **very old** PHP version! See updated answer. The code is working, see Demo link!

Comment: My php version is 7.4.3

Comment: Then, arrow syntax must work. You need to distinct between php-cli and php-fpm. Again, look at the demo link to see it is working! Otherwise just use the OLD version code I`ve added. https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arrow.php

Comment: **Below PHP 7.4 use** This answer worked for me

Comment: Because your version is below 7.4. See proof https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arrow.php

Comment: Please mention it in the answer to have a particular version of php to have it working

Comment: There is a below 7.4 use hint! Read answers completely, not partly. Btw, you should upgrade to modern version and tag (old) version in the question!

Comment: That you have added later not before i tried to use arrow function

Comment: For the above function i'm telling to mention the compatible version

Comment: No. If you tag it PHP I must assume you are using the [current stable version](https://www.php.net/) which is today 8.1. If you use an old version, you need to tag or say it in the question. Your comment ` unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW)` makes it clear, you have an old version. When you have a problem with Windows, everybody assumes you are using 10/11 not 95/XP.

Answer (score -3):

You have an array like:

```
$array = [
" test",
"test foo ",
"test bar",
"test foo bar"
];
```

loop over it like this:

```
foreach($array as &$arr) {
    $arr = str_replace(" ", "", $arr);
}

print_r($array);
```

result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => test
    [1] => testfoo
    [2] => testbar
    [3] => testfoobar
)
```

BR

Comment: They want to filter out elements with only spaces, not remove all spaces from all elements.

Comment: Its not really clear what OP wants..Either to remove white spaces or to remove white spavce elemetes, or to filter them out.

Comment: Since they are mentioning array_filter and say that it doesn't work on double spaces, I would say it's pretty clear. Either way, they have clarified it in comments as well now. Also, if you think a question is unclear, I would recommend that you rather wait to write an answer until the OP has clarified it.